# How can I ensure my_custom_module.install runs my_custom_module_update_8101()?

Tags: hooks

I have a custom module in Drupal 8.9.3. `hook_schema()` runs and creates the module table. I would like to run a `hook_update_N()` implementation to change the auto increment to start at a specific number, but it doesn't appear to run.

```php
function my_custom_module_update_8101() {
  $sql = 'alter table {my_custom_table}  AUTO_INCREMENT = 100000000000;';
  Database::getConnection()->exec($sql);
}
```

I heard there's a table where I can see my custom module is installed, and what version of the schema it's on, but I am unable to locate these tables. And the tables I do find appear the value is blob format so I cannot read it easily. Any ideas what I'm doing incorrectly?

Comment: https://www.gistshare.com/notes/98/how-check-current-schema-version-module-drupal

Comment: Put it in hook_install?

Comment: The main problem isn't the hook implemented, but the code it runs (`Database::getConnection()->exec($sql);`).

Answer (score 3):

Update hooks are there to get the module into a known good state - the same state as when the module gets installed. It's for when you need to make changes to an already installed module, I'm not sure there's a scenario where it would make sense to include an update hook in a new module.

As leymannx mentioned in the comments, [`hook_install()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Extension%21module.api.php/function/hook_install/9.4.x) is the best place for your code. It's invoked after the schema is installed, so you'll be able to make your changes there.

Answer (score 2):

In the code shown in the question, `Database::getConnection()->exec($sql)` will cause an error, since the object returned by `Database::getConnection()` (a [`Connection`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Database%21Connection.php/class/Connection/9.3.x) object) doesn't have any `exec()` method.
If then the file containing the `my_custom_module_update_8101` function doesn't include a `use Drupal\Core\Database\Database;` line, PHP will throw an error about a not found class.

Hooks implemented by Drupal core modules use [`\Drupal::database()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal.php/function/Drupal%3A%3Adatabase/9.3.x) to query the database.
To execute a generic SQL query, you should use `\Drupal::database()->query()`, for example in `hook_install()`, for the reasons given after.

```php
Drupal::database()->query('ALTER TABLE {my_custom_table} AUTO_INCREMENT = 100000000000;');
```

If you installed the module and edited its .install file to add that hook, it doesn't work because Drupal caches the list of hooks implemented by modules and it won't notice a new hook is added until a new module is installed or an existing module is uninstalled.

If you installed a module that already implements `my_custom_module_update_8101()`, that hook won't be invoked because the module is installed, not updated. `hook_update_N()` is for modules that are updated.
When a module is installed, Drupal records the higher number used from an update hook; it will execute the update hook with a number that is higher than that, when the module is updated. This means that, installing a module that already implements `my_custom_module_update_8101()`, Drupal will never invoke that hook, even when the module is later updated.

The only hook that is invoked when a module is installed is `hook_install()`. That is the hook you should use.
Keep in mind that, if the module is already installed, you need to uninstall it and  re-install it, to make Drupal run its installation hook.